# Media Element Player Exit Full Screen Scrolling Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I have long web page that scrolls vertically with several videos.   Using Media Element Player, the videos play, but if you enter full screen mode and then exit full screen mode, the page returns to the very top, regardless of where the video is on the page.   I want it to return to the same place.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
var topPosition;

MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen_org =         
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen;
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen = function() {
    console.log('enter full screen');
    this.enterFullScreen_org();
    topPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(topPosition);
}

MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen_org = 
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen;
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen = function() {
    console.log('exit full screen')
    this.exitFullScreen_org();
    ResetFullScreen();
}

function ResetFullScreen() {
    console.log('top pos:', topPosition);
    setTimeout(function () { window.scrollTo(0, topPosition) }, 500);
}
```

The console.log shows the correct value for "topPosition" but the window.scrollTo method doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your code, it appears that it should work. I do, however, have one more method to setting the scroll that may work. This will be useful if the element you're trying to scroll is not at the top level.

When storing the scroll position:

```
topPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
```

When setting the scroll position:

```
document.body.scrollTop = topPosition;
```

If what you're trying to scroll is an element within the body, and not the body itself, just replace `document.body` with the element you need to scroll.

Also, I found a little thing in your code:

```
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen;'
```

There's a random quote at the end of that line.

---

EDIT:

If that method does not work, I have one more idea for you. When they click on the video they view, store the element that they clicked on in a variable. After leaving fullscreen, scroll the element into view. That way, you will be, more or less, where the screen was when it entered fullscreen.

Each video has an onclick containing the following; this stores the element they clicked on.

```
lastVideoClicked = event.target;
```

When leaving fullscreen, this code will attempt to scroll that element back into view.

```
lastVideoClicked.scrollIntoView();
```

You can try it out on the Stack Overflow site right here - scroll to the bottom of the page, open your javascript console, and enter the code `document.getElementById('hlogo').scrollIntoView()`. This scrolls the Stack Overflow logo into view.

Comment: That would work, but for some reason, after exiting full screen, the document.body.scrollTop property does not work.  It works before the enter/exit of the full screen, but not after.  I tested on the console.

Comment: That's really weird... I've never seen that happening before. I'm going to add to the answer one more method I can think of...

Comment: I confirm that with the current version of the browsers, you need to record the `document.body` / `document.documentElement` `scrollTop` property before entering the fullscreen mode, and restore the property once the fullscreen experience is over.